# asp.net web site - add version number automatically?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Is it possible in an asp.net web site project for it to increment a build version number automatically (and display it to our test team)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, in the AssemblyInfo.cs (or .vb, I guess) you can specify an `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.*")]` attribute. The "*" means that that part of the 4-part number is generated automatically (it's based on date and time).

You can read out that version number using this code:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

That AssemblyInfo file should exist in every project, nowadays within a Properties folder.

Comment: I guess same question as above. This is a web site project which is not producing a dll, this would probably work if it was a web application project?

Answer (score 5):

In order to autoincrement the version of the assembly at each build you could use the following assembly attribute:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

and to read the version at runtime of the currently executing assembly you could use the [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.version.aspx) property:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

Comment: Will this work on an asp.net web site project which is not producing a dll (except what it builds in the windows temp .net folder)?

Comment: No probably it won't work. It would be better to place this code into a custom assembly over which you have control and call it from code behind.